# Not passing id into model in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using Eloquent's `firstOrCreate()` method to insert my data, or retrieve if it exists.

I need to get the `$trip->id`. If I `echo` it in the FlightController then it `echo`'s the correct `id`, but it doesn't seem to pass it into the UserFlights Model to insert into the `user_flights` table.

I get this error on the page:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_trips_id' cannot be null (SQL:
>   insert into `user_flights` (`airport_from`, `airport_to`,
>   `user_trips_id`) values (1, 4, ))

**Flow:** User select's two airports (flying from and flying to) from the drop-down boxes (`<select>`) and adds them to their "trip". If they don't have a trip, it creates one, and then adds the two airports to their trip.

**Schema**

```
# `user_trips` table
Schema::create('user_trips', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
     $table->text('name');
});
# `user_flights ` table
Schema::create('user_flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->integer('trip_id')->unsigned();
     $table->integer('airport_from')->unsigned();
     $table->integer('airport_to')->unsigned();
     $table->foreign('trip_id')->references('id')->on('user_trips')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**FlightController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\UserFlights;
use App\UserTrips;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class FlightController
 *
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class FlightController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserTrips $user_trips_obj
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(Request $request, UserTrips $user_trips_obj)
    {
        // Retrieve the trip by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
        $trip=$user_trips_obj->addTrip();

        # Returns the ID correctly.
        //echo $trip->id;exit;

        $user_trips_obj->addFlight(
            new UserFlights([
                'airport_from'=>$request->flight_from,
                'airport_to'=>$request->flight_to,
                # Does not pass the `$trip->id` into the UserFlights model.
                'user_trips_id'=>$trip->id
            ])
        );

        return back();
    }
}
```

**UserTrips Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class UserTrips
 *
 */
class UserTrips extends Model
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps=FALSE;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable=[
        'name',
        'user_id'
    ];

    /**
     * @param UserFlights $user_flights_obj
     * @return Model
     */
    public function addFlight(UserFlights $user_flights_obj)
    {
        return $this->userflights()->save($user_flights_obj);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function userflights()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserFlights');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function addTrip()
    {
        // Retrieve the trip by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
        $trip=$this->firstOrCreate([
            'user_id'=>1,
            'name'=>'My Trip'
        ]);

        return $trip;
    }
}
```

**UserFlights Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class UserFlights
 *
 */
class UserFlights extends Model
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps=FALSE;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable=[
        'airport_from',
        'airport_to',
        'user_trips_id'
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function usertrips()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\UserTrips');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked into the error message `Column 'user_trips_id' cannot be null` this seems to be the issue, not the id  you have no value in the data but the DB filed is set to ALLOW NULL - false more likely  so need s a value in the user_trips_id data?

Comment: @SimonDavies I understand the error but the `user_trips_id` shouldn't be NULL. Like I said, I can see the correct ID in the FlightController but it's not getting passed into the UserFlights model. Maybe I am not understanding you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addFlight()` method calls `$this->userflights()->save($user_flights_obj);`.

When you call `save()` on the relationship object, it sets the foreign key on the object passed in (`$user_flights_obj`) to the id of the object that owns the relationship (`$this`). Then it saves the `$user_flights_obj` object.

Since your controller calls `$user_trips_obj->addFlight(new UserFlights...)`, the `$this` reference inside your `addFlight()` method is referencing the `$user_trips_obj` instance from your controller. This instance is just an empty shell, with a blank id. Therefore, inside your `addFlight()` method, when you call `save()` on the relationship, it is going to set the foreign key on your new `UserFlights` instance to the id of the instance on which `addFlight()` was called (blank).

To solve this issue, you just need to call `addFlight()` on the `$trip` instance you created in the controller. That is the instance to which you want to relate the new `UserFlights` instance. Additionally, you don't need to set the foreign key manually; that is the whole reason for calling `save()` on the relationship.

Comment: Right. Thank you. Works now

Comment: @Draven When you create your `new UserFlights()`, you are manually assigning the `user_trips_id` field. This is not needed if you're going to pass this object into the `save()` method on the relationship, since that is what the save method does.